# Shortcut for indent line from the beginning in Intellij?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I have tried using tab but it causes indentation from the point where the cursor was there. Is there any shortcut for moving line by one tab from the beginning of the line, not from the point of the cursor?

Answer (score 0):

You could map custom shortcut for "Indent Line or Selection" action in "File | Settings | Keymap - Other"